# Powershell in Windows 7 versus Server 2008 - differences?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7-x64

Referencing this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024439/powershell-script-to-rename-all-files-in-directory), what might be the difference between running this on Windows 7 Professional and Server 2008 R2?
Server 2008 R2 IS running PS version 2.0 whereas my Windows 7 machine is running 1.0.
Would this be enough to cause the following issue (this works correctly until the final trip through the directory, which then throws the error shown below - over and over and over again):

[image]

**Here is the PS script from that posting:**

```
$dir_files = "C:\path\to\my\files"
$new = "newFile.xml"
$chkFile = "C:\path\to\my\files\newFile.xml"
$fileExists = Test-Path $chkFile

while($true) {
    $xmlFiles = gci $dir_files -include pre_name_*.xml -recurse

    if ($xmlFiles.Length -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "No files in "$dir_Files". Shutting down."
         break
    }

    foreach ($file in $xmlFiles) {
        [string]$strfile = $file
        if (Test-Path $chkFile) {
            Write-Host $chkFile + " file exists! Sleeping 20 seconds ..."
            Start-Sleep -s 20
        } else {        
            if (Test-Path $strfile){        
                Write-Host $chkFile " doesn't exist, renaming next file in array..."
                rename-item -path $file -newname ("$new")
                Start-Sleep -s 10
            } else{
                Write-Host $file " does not exist. Last file processed. Exiting..."
                break
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

The gist of this is to run through a list of files in a directory and, once a specific type is found, rename it. That renamed file gets processed and deleted and then the next one needs to be renamed until none are left. Then, it will quit/break.
The script works fine on the Windows 7 machine. Not so much on the Server 2008 R2 machine. Both are 64bit.

Per request, fleshing request out more fully. Taken from original posting:
The original intention was more fully fleshed out in the original posting. Sorry, I tried to keep the original request short but caused more confusion: 
**Task:** Directory that will have various .csv files dumped into it. These could be like file1.csv, file2.csv, etc. 
**Problem:** Iterate through the files and rename one to a standardized 'newfilename.csv'. This file will then be processed by an external program and get renamed and moved out of the directory. 
This does not run 24/7. It will be a scheduled task and run until there are no more files in the directory. No sub directories.

**UPDATE/FINAL CODE:**

```
$dir_files = "C:\path\to\my\files"
$new = "newFile.xml"
$chkFile = "C:\path\to\my\files\newFile.xml"
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922997/powershell-in-windows-7-versus-server-2008-differences

#changed Include to Filter to improve performance
$xmlFiles = gci $dir_files -include pre_name*.xml -recurse

if (@($xmlFiles).Count -eq 0) {
   Write-Host "No files in '$dir_Files'. Shutting down."
   break
}

foreach ($file in $xmlFiles) {
   #wait until last file is removed (processed by external app)
   while (Test-Path $chkFile){
      Write-Host "$chkFile file exists! Sleeping 20 seconds ..."
      Start-Sleep -s 20
   }
   #continue with the next file
   [string]$strfile = $file
   if (($strFile) -and (Test-Path $strFile)){
      Write-Host "$chkFile doesn't exist, renaming next file in array, sleeping 10 seconds ..."
      Rename-Item -Path $file -newname ("$new")
      Start-Sleep -s 10
   }    
}
```

Comment: This question contains so many errors.... 1st: first you say you have 2008 server and a win7, then you say 2008 r2 later on, which server is it? 2nd: Win7 CAN'T have powershell 1, because powershell 2 is default in the OS. 3rd: when including code in a question, make sure the sample is complete. Your script above refers to variables that doesn't exist. 4th: you're searching through and renaming files recursively, yet you only check if the "newfilename" is "busy" in the root folder. Suddenly you have `c:\logs\subfolder\newfilename.csv` still processing, while `test-path` checks `c:\logs\newf..`

Comment: As previously stated, Windows 7 cannot possibly run PowerShell 1.0, unless someone has done some major hacking to make it work. I can think of no reason why that would be beneficial.

Comment: Corrected per request: 1) corrected to all state Windows Server 2008 R2, 2) corrected to state Windows 7 Professional using PS 3.0, 3) included complete code rather than snippet from previous posting & 4) I believe this is clarified by including the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were after? I've cleaned up/rewritten the code(untested), but as I don't completely understand what you're trying to do it may be wrong.

```
$dir_files = "C:\path\to\my\files"
$new = "newFile.xml"
$chkFile = "C:\path\to\my\files\newFile.xml"
$fileExists = Test-Path $chkFile

#Changed Include to Filter to improve performance.
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir_files -Filter pre_name_*.xml

if (@($xmlFiles).Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No files in '$dir_files'. Shutting down."
    break
}

foreach ($file in $xmlFiles) {
    #Wait until last file is removed(processed by external app)
    while (Test-Path $chkFile) {
        Write-Host "$chkFile file exists! Sleeping 20 seconds ..."
        Start-Sleep -s 20
    }
    #Continue with next file
    Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $new
    Start-Sleep -s 10
}
```

To find out what caused the error in your original script, you should run the script using PowerShell ISE and set a breakpoint at `if (Test-Path $strfile){` so you can see the value of `$strfile` each time and detect what happends to it, because as the error says, `$strfile` suddenly becomes blank (Path property is empty).

Comment: The original intention was more fully fleshed out in the original posting. Sorry, I tried to keep the original request short but caused more confusion: **Task**:
Directory that will have various .csv files dumped into it. These could be like file1.csv, file2.csv, etc.
**Problem**:
Iterate thru the files and rename one to a standardized 'newfilename.csv'.This file will then be processed by an external program and get renamed and moved out of the directory. This does not run 24/7.It will be a scheduled task and run until there are no more files in the directory.No sub directories.-edited OP too-

Comment: Then my edited answer should work. `-Recurse` is unnecessary if you're not searching through subfolders, and the while-loop is unnecessary if it's a scheduled job and not a "service" running 24/7.

Comment: I updated the OP to include final code used. It is slightly modified but you've got me there. The "-Rename-Item" would throw an error if there were no files to begin with in the directory so I included a check there. Also, the use of '-Filter' versus '-include' for performance reasons was a non-issue as there won't be more than a handful of files and using '-Filter' with '-Get-ChildItem' threw errors (whereas the initial usage of gci and '-include' did not. This is my first PowerShell exposure so I can't explain the difference or reason for this but, in the end, it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance the negative marks can be removed from the original question now that I've clarified it further?

Comment: Down votes can be removed by the people who gave you the negative marks now that you have updated your question. Also they can be countered by up votes of course.

Comment: Notice that I also changed you filecount to `@($xmlfiles).Count` to ensure that it count items(`length` will return filesize if it's only one file), and by dropping the `while($true)`-loop, `Rename-Item` should never run against an unexisting file. :-)

Comment: Lars Truijens, yes, that is what I was requesting. Frode F- Yes, I did change that as well but, somehow, it was still falling through to the Rename-Item. But it is working this way now. You definitely got me there. Thanks!